# When Angular directive's name really matters

Tags: javascript, html, forms, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've just come across a strange behavior from Angular:

Here's the scenario:

In a registration form, I want to check for email uniqueness (through an http call to server).
Thus, I created a directive called `emailUnique` whose client code is:

```
<form name="form" novalidate>
<!-- some other fields -->
<input name="email" type="email" ng-model="user.email" required email-unique/>
</form>
```

For the rest of the post, let's suppose that user is typing: `michael`, that is clearly not a valid mail.

Let's take a look at the interesting portion of my directive code, triggering the behavior I'm interested to:

```
angular.module('directives.emailUnique', [])
    .directive('emailUnique', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {
                ctrl.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
                    console.log(viewValue);   //What do you expect here for viewValue? answer below
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

Before giving the answer, at first glance, the response would logically be:

```
undefined
```

Why? Because:

- We precise the `type="email"` attribute and not simply `type="text"`
- `michael` isn't a valid mail.
- Angular's compiler is supposed to conform to classic HTML behavior.

After testing it, the answer is `undefined` as expected. My complete directive's logic will be based on that and the whole works fine.

Now, let's rename the directive: `emailUnique` becoming `somethingUnique`.
Client being now:

```
<input name="email" type="email" ng-model="user.email" required something-unique/>
```

Surprise: the `console.log(viewValue)` is now displaying: `michael`, not `undefined` ...

Clearly, starting with `email` for the name has a strange effect when dealing with an email field in this case.

My question is simple: **Is there a good reason? A possible bug? Might I misunderstand some notion?**

Some further precisions:

- The [Angular's documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3ainput.email) about Email field with angular does not present some `email` attribute that could interfere with `email-unique`. Indeed, it's based on the `type="email"`
- I came across the same issue whether the form's `novalidate` attribute is present or not.

Comment: Here's a plunkr I've just made to show the issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/T9YfiDr5IU5vOrMtggY3?p=preview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is the directive's priority.  Since you are dependent on the timing of when your parsers are added you want to set the directive's priority- that will ensure the timing you need.

In your demo the `somethingUnique` directive is running before validation has been added to the parsers list (it ends up the middle of 3 parsers).  Whereas with `emailUnique` it's added after.

Setting the priority of your directive to something over 0 ensures it fires after emailValidation giving you `undefined` always (noting from the [$compile docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile): "post-link functions are run in reverse order").  To confirm this you can force `emailUnique` to fail by setting it's priority to something less than 0.

So this fixes the problem:

```
.directive('somethingUnique', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        priority: 100,
        link: function (scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
                console.log(viewValue);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

[Updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/w8HH2v7T3ktD4NT8j2Ft?p=preview)

**Update on the name issue:**  It appears that Angular processes directives with the same priority in alphabetical order.  So `homethingUnique` acts like `emailUnique` since both come before `input` while `jomehtingUnique` behaves like `somethingUnique`- running after input.

But [Angular's docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile) say: "The order of directives with the same priority is undefined."  So we can't count on alphabetical order.

Comment: Awesome. "Why the name seems to matter here is a puzzle that I want to dig into more" => very curious to know the reason too.

Comment: Great, very interesting :) But one question: the more the directive's `priority` is high, the more its parser will run early, won't it? If I set 100 for somethingUnique, why doesn't its corresponding parser run BEFORE emailValidation, since it would be pushed the first? supposing emailValidation has the default 0. –

Comment: The key is this bit from the docs: "Pre-link functions are also run in priority order, but post-link functions are run in reverse order".  Here's an update where you can watch the priority 1 get added then the priority 100:  http://plnkr.co/edit/0IFg5xMyDUtyMcB3hqTk?p=preview  (note I pass in scope on one and viewValue to the other so you can identify each in the parsers chain)

Comment: Indeed! Thanks a lot :) I've learned a lot of things thanks to this post.